# MessageChannelPartitionHandler consumes the first available reply from QueueChannel and thus completing wrong job

Tags: spring-integration

I am seeing the same problem as stated here

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/724241-s-integration-s-batch-remote-step-execution-problem?view=thread
I have multiple jobs running which has step that use same parent partition hanldler 'parentPartitionHandler'defined below

```
<bean id="parentPartitionHandler"class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler>
<property name="gridSize" value="3"/>
<property name="replyChannel" ref="outboundReplies"/>
<property name="messagingOperations">
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate">
  <property name="defaultChannel" ref="outboundRequests"/>
            <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="stepName" value="parentPartitionStep"/>
</bean>
```

All of my jobs have similar configuration like below with 2nd step 'studentPartitionAndProcessStep'  being partition step

```
<job id="studentLoadJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
     job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="true" parent="abstractJob">
    <step id="studentLoadStep" parent="parentLoadStep" next="studentPartitionAndProcessStep"/>
    <step id="studentPartitionAndProcessStep" next="studentCleanupStep">
        <partition partitioner="filePartitioner" handler="studentPartitionHandler"/>
    </step>
    <step id="studentCleanupStep" parent="parentCleanupStep"/>
</job>

<bean id="studentPartitionHandler"
      parent="parentPartitionHandler">
    <property name="stepName" value="studentPartitionStep"/>
</bean>
```

I used the same master configuration from here https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/remotePartition.xml

```
<int:channel id="outboundReplies">
 <int:queue/>
 </int:channel>

<int:channel id="inboundStaging">
</int:channel>

<int:aggregator ref="parentPartitionHandler" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" send-timeout="60000000"
                input-channel="inboundStaging" output-channel="outboundReplies"
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>
```

Problem I have is aggregator seems to collect the messages of a group correctly but inside MessageChannelPartitionHandler the below statement receives the first available message without being taking the header information from the message.

```
Message<Collection<StepExecution>> message = (Message<Collection<StepExecution>>) messagingGateway.receive(replyChannel);
```

So PartitionHandler handles the result of jobExecutionA instead of jobExecutionB and therefore it is completing a wrong job.

It seems that MessageChannelPartitionHandler consumes the reply from QueueChannel (outboundReplies in my configuration) without taking into consideration the correlationId but the first available message. It works some times and then it doesn't and then when I debug I found the same thing happening to me as the post here

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/724241-s-integration-s-batch-remote-step-execution-problem?view=thread

Is there something I am doing wrong here?
 I can provide more configuration if you need.

EDIT:
With Gateways all working good. I am also trying to work this with Adapters and add header-enricher so the replyChannel object is added to the header. I added a header-enricher element but I might be using it wrong because when aggregate message hanlder throws "no outputChannel or replyChannel header available".
All partition requests are sent on outboundRequests channel and to rabbit queue where slaves will consume the requests from inboundRequestschannel where service activator process them and send back to reply queue on outboundStaging channel. On the master side partition response messages are read by aggregator from inboundStaging channel.Can you point where exactly I need to use header-enricher when using adapters.

```
<int:channel id="outboundRequests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" failover="true"/>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="inboundStaging"/>
<int:channel id="inboundRequests"/>
<int:channel id="outboundStaging"/>
<int:channel id="setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel"/>


<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="filePartitionRequestOutboundGateway"
        channel="outboundRequests"
        amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
        exchange-name="${rabbitmq.classflow.exchange}"
        routing-key="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.partition.routingkey}"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
        />


<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="filePartitionRequestInboundGateway"
        concurrent-consumers="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.partition.consumers}"
        channel="inboundRequests"
        receive-timeout="60000000"
        queue-names="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.partition.queuename.request}"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
        />

<int:header-enricher input-channel="setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel" output-channel="outboundRequests">
    <int:header-channels-to-string/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:service-activator ref="stepExecutionRequestHandler" input-channel="inboundRequests"
                       output-channel="outboundStaging"/>


<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="filePartitionRepyOutboundGateway"
        channel="outboundStaging"
        amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
        exchange-name="${rabbitmq.classflow.exchange}"
        routing-key="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.partition.queuename.reply.routingkey}"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
 />

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="filePartitionRepyInboundGateway"
        channel="inboundStaging"
        queue-names="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.partition.queuename.reply}"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        concurrent-consumers="${rabbitmq.classflow.batch.tenant.job.consumers}"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
   />

<int:aggregator ref="parentPartitionHandler"
                send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
                send-timeout="60000000"
                input-channel="inboundStaging"/>

<bean id="parentPartitionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler">
    <property name="gridSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="messagingOperations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate">
            <property name="defaultChannel" ref="setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel"/>
            <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="stepName" value="parentPartitionStep"/>
</bean>
```

LOGGING:

13:46:09.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.i.p.MessageChannelPartitionHandler - Sending request: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (MessageChannelPartitionHandler.java:222) 
13:46:09.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.567 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.567 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.568 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (LoggingHandler.java:160) 
13:46:09.568 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) 
13:46:09.568 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0 received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.568 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.570 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.572 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.c.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry - Registered org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170 as 771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1 (DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry.java:167) 
13:46:09.572 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.572 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.573 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler - handler 'org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0' sending reply Message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:238) 
13:46:09.573 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.ExecutorChannel - preSend on channel 'outboundRequests', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.574 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.574 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.574 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (LoggingHandler.java:160) 
13:46:09.574 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) 
13:46:09.575 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.ExecutorChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outboundRequests', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) 
13:46:09.575 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.a.o.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0 received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.577 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@f89f170, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=b39d71de-b469-667f-2d77-e59db6e0e25a, timestamp=1425494769566}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) 
13:46:09.578 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[correlationId] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.578 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[sequenceSize] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.578 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[sequenceNumber] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.579 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@127.0.0.1:5672/activfounlocal,13) (RabbitTemplate.java:1043) 
13:46:09.579 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Publishing message on exchange [classflow.topic], routingKey = [partition.request.*] (RabbitTemplate.java:1071) 
13:46:09.579 [taskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.i.a.o.AmqpOutboundEndpoint - handler 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0' produced no reply for request Message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, replyChannel=771064f6-d5ae-4f50-b827-00c225a36c86:1, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=77608d25-cff4-4f3d-9f60-829f05f7bd6f, timestamp=1425494769573}] (AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:184) 
13:46:09.580 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.580 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[amqp_deliveryMode] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.580 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[amqp_receivedExchange] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.580 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[correlationId] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[sequenceSize] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.a.s.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[sequenceNumber] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* (AbstractHeaderMapper.java:240) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'inboundRequests', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:334) 
13:46:09.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.582 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (LoggingHandler.java:160) 
13:46:09.582 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'loggerChannel', message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (AbstractMessageChannel.java:349) 
13:46:09.582 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.h.ServiceActivatingHandler - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@d15c892] received message: [Payload StepExecutionRequest content=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=56, stepExecutionId=269, stepName=studentPartitionStep]][Headers={amqp_receivedRoutingKey=partition.request.*, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, correlationId=56:studentPartitionStep, sequenceSize=1, amqp_receivedExchange=classflow.topic, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceNumber=0, id=e51f8ed9-03df-0f90-b9c2-c3542bda76c6, timestamp=1425494769581}] (AbstractMessageHandler.java:72) 
13:46:09.599 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'studentPartitionStep' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.658 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) 
13:46:09.659 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Executing: id=269 (AbstractStep.java:183)

Thanks
Mallikarjun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Spring Batch 3.0.3 as long as you don't inject a specific `replyChannel` into the partition handler.

`spring-batch-integration` is now part of the main [Spring Batch project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch).

**EDIT**

In response to your last comment (about using adapters instead of gateways).

Yes; the gateway takes care of keeping the `replyChannel` header intact. There's some extra config needed when using adapters:

- Add a header enricher with a `<header-channels-to-string/>` element (see [the Header Channel Registry documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-channel-registry)); this converts the live header channel object to a key for the channel registry.
- Configure the adapters to map the `replyChannel` header (e.g. `mapped-request-headers="*"`).

This is not needed for the gateway because it holds a reference to the outbound message when the reply is received.

Comment: I changed my spring-batch version from 3.0.1 to 3.0.3.  I commented out the replyChanel reference from my partition handler from my above post.  
 The problem now is that partition handler it waits indefinitely and wont return on receive(currentReplyChannel).

 I verified aggregator processed group and replied message to outputChannel 'outboundReplies' but I commented this from partition handler.
 
    <int:aggregator ref="parentPartitionHandler" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" send-timeout="60000000"
                    input-channel="inboundStaging" output-channel="outboundReplies"/>

Comment: Please don't add code to comments; it's unreadable - edit your question instead. Remove the output-channel from the aggregator (there is no output-channel in the example you linked to) and the aggregator will automatically return the reply to the internal reply channel in the partition handler.

Comment: sorry, in my configuration posted above I was using the aggregator with output channel. Yeah, the post I referenced is not using it. I will remove the output-channel from my configuration and try.

Comment: Hi Gary, after removing the output channel from aggregator AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage throws "no outputChannel or replyChannel header available" .. do I need to add the replyChaneel as part of the header?

Comment: No; that means you've lost the internal reply channel somehow - shouldn't happen if you are using Michael's config; it might be better if you edit your question with your current configuration.

Comment: Yeah, the only change I made is to have inbound and outbound adapters instead of Gateways. I can change as per the Michael's config and give it a try. I hope I made a mistaking while replacing Gateways by adapters. I got it working with Gateways at one point but to get rig of the issue I have I started to change the code and ended up with adapters

Comment: changing it to Gateways resolved it. I will play around with multiple jobs and update you and mark the answer as correct. I really appreciate for your swift response any time.

Comment: I have tested with multiple jobs and all looks good . I do have one more question , is there was to discard replies from step execution requests or even discard the previous job and its steps execution request after server is restarted or  something goes wrong? I can post it as another question if it is irrelevant to this post.

Comment: Ask another question; with more details of the use case.

Comment: I just edited my post with my current configuration. I might be doing wrong with header-enricher element and tis is the first time I have actually used it. When I tried I still get that error where replyChannel header was missing uwing Adapters. [With Gateways all works great].

Comment: No; you need to put the enricher __between__ the partition handler and the outbound adapter `<int:header-enricher input-channel="fromHandler" output-channel="outboundRequests">` (and change the handler to send to fromHandler). The way you have it now, you have the enricher competing with the adapter for the messages (they are subscribed to the same channel).

Comment: I updated my the configuration as per the last comment added header-enricher  between handler[setHeaderPartionHandlerReplyChannel] and outbound-adapter[outboundRequests channel] and verified replyChanel header is available as a string on outboundrequests Channel. The problem now is the header got lost on inboundRequests channel on the slave side after receiveing from the rabbit queue. I have set the mapped-request-headers="*" on the outbound-channel-adapter as you can see in my configuration. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hmmm - it should be mapped ok; turn on DEBUG logging; it puts out lots of information about header mapping.

Comment: Hi Gary, I added logging info to the post. What I observed is when publishing message on rabbit (from outboundRequest) the message has the header replyChannel but then immediately I see all header names with "DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper - headerName=[sequenceNumber] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=* " except replyChannel and on the consumer side on inboundRequests channel replyChannel header is not available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72261/discussion-between-mallikarjun-and-gary-russell).

Comment: After debugging I noticed that replyChannel is defined as the TRANSIENT_HEADER_NAMES in AbstractHeaderMapper and thus is not excluded from the final header list of amqpMessageProperties .headers. I am I missing something or doing wrong?

Comment: Right - as I said in the chat, this was changed in 4.1.x. If you can't move to 4.1.2, the work around is to use a different header; we worked around it in Spring XD until we moved to 4.1 with [by using a different header name](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/batch/singlestep-partition-support.xml#L48) also see [line 58](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/batch/singlestep-partition-support.xml#L58). But it's simpler to use 4.1.x.

Comment: Hi Gary, I had a question and sent you in chat. Can you please look at it or you want me to add here as comment